# Integration Testing multipart/form-data c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, web-api-testing

I have trouble trying to create an integration test for my post call that accepts a viewmodel that has amongst other values, an IFormFile, which makes this call from an application/json to a multipart/form-data

My IntegrationSetup class

```
protected static IFormFile GetFormFile()
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test;test;");

            var file = new FormFile(
                baseStream: new MemoryStream(bytes),
                baseStreamOffset: 0,
                length: bytes.Length,
                name: "Data",
                fileName: "dummy.csv"
            )
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = "text/csv"
            };

            return file;
        }
```

My Test Method

```
public async Task CreateAsync_ShouldReturnId()
        {
            //Arrange
            using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var stringContent = new StringContent(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CreateArticleViewmodel
                {
                    Title = "viewModel.Title",
                    SmallParagraph = "viewModel.SmallParagraph",
                    Url = "viewModel.Url",
                    Image = GetFormFile()
                }),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");
            stringContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"json\"");
            content.Add(stringContent, "json");

            //Act
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{Url}", content);
            //Assert
            response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            int id = int.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            id.ShouldBeGreaterThan(0);
        }
```

My Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateArticleAsync([FromForm] CreateArticleViewmodel viewModel)
        {

            var id = await _service.CreateAsync(viewModel).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (id > 0)
                return Ok(id);
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

It throws a BadRequest without getting inside the method.

Comment: You should not be using `application/json` content-type.

Comment: I’ve tried with multipart/form-data but I had the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are posting the request contents to the API, in your code, is not correct.

When the API expects a `FileInfo` in the request payload, posting JSON content never works. You need to send the payload as `MultipartFormData` and not as JSON.

Consider following example.

This is a an API endpoint which expects and model with FileInfo in it as payload.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] MyData myData)
{
    if (myData.File != null)
    {
        return Ok("File received");
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("File no provided");
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // Below property is used for getting file from client to the server.
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

This is pretty much the same API as yours.

Following is the client code which calls the above API with file and other model properties.

```
var apiURL = "http://localhost:50492/home/upload";
const string filename = "D:\\samplefile.docx";

HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

// Instead of JSON body, multipart form data will be sent as request body.
var httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

// Add File property with file content
httpContent.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);

// Add id property with its value
httpContent.Add(new StringContent("789"), "id");

// Add title property with its value.
httpContent.Add(new StringContent("Some title value"), "title");

// send POST request.
var response = await _client.PostAsync(apiURL, httpContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// output the response content to the console.
Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
```

The client code is running from a Console application. So when I run this, the expectation is to get `File received` message in the console and I am getting that message.

[image: console output]

Following is the screen capture of the model content at the API end while debugging it.

[image: API Debugging capture]

And if I am calling this API from postman, it would look like following.

[image: Postman capture]

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: It worked that way. I think it's weird that you have to break the viewmodel down and add each field to the content instead of what I was trying to do, which works when you have "simple" value types like "int",string,"decimal","bool", etc probably because everything is treated as a string.

Comment: When data is sent as multipart form data, they need to be added as form fields individually... you can send the complex data too if you have class property in the main model.